# Word Document Collaboration on Live Version

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-word

We are using Sharepoint to collaborate on a training Word document that will be quite large.  My goal is to have two people (myself or my boss) approve any changes to the document before the changes are shown to others.  Does anyone know of a way to do this?

My fall back plan is to have the contributors e-mail us changes that we will then approve before they are added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go the the versioning settings page of your library (settings -> site library settings -> versioning settings).
Answer "yes" to the question **"Require content approval for submitted items?"**, and make sure to choose the **"Only users who can approve items (and the author of the item)"** radio button under **"Draft Item Security"**.
Then you'll have to change the permissions so that only your boss and yourself have the necessary credentials to approve items in this library.